# Как перегрузить оператор ввода с использованием getline?

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, перегрузка-операторов, fstream

К примеру есть класс Person с перегруженными операторами ввода и вывода.

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person()
    {
        name = "Empty";
        age = 0;
    }

    Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Person& obj)
    {
        return out << setw(10) << obj.name << setw(5) << obj.age << endl;
    }

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Person& obj)
    {
       return in >> obj.name >> obj.age;
    }

private:
    string name;
    int age;
};
```

Я записываю данные в файл с помощью fstream

```
Person st("Name Surname", 66);

fstream fs;
fs.open("person.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);

fs << st;
```

Далее я хочу извлечь данные из файла

```
while (true)
{
    Person temp;
    fs >> temp;
    if (fs.eof())
    {
        break;
    }
    cout << temp;
}
```

Проблема в том, что при вводе string, если ввожу так "Name Surname", т.е с пробелом между, то появляется сбой. Я пытался перегрузить >> с использованием getline:

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Person& obj)
{
    getline(in, obj.name);
    in >> obj.age;
    return in;
}
```

Но корректно извлечь не удалось. Каким образом следует перегрузить оператор ввода для корректной работы string с файлами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот где то так

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Person& obj)
{
   std::string lastname, firstname;
   in >> lastname >> firstname >> obj.age;
   obj.name = lastname + " " + firstname;
   return in;
}
```

Если вдруг имя-фамилия будут состоять из трех и более слов, то тут придется выдумывать.